# D3 4.0 Graph with directed edges and labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am trying to create a graph with d3 (v4.0) that has directed edges and labels for the nodes, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/HgHqy/ but with a newer version of D3.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/4nu57pgn/1/ but I can't seem to figure out how to tell D3 to make the edges appear visually directed (with arrows) or to have the node IDs displayed.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var width = svg.attr("width");
var height = svg.attr("height");
svg = svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)).append("g");
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

function createGraph (error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.type); });


  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { if (d.root == "true") return color(d.root); return color(d.type); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.on("click",function(d){
    console.log("clicked", d.id);
  });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + "," + d3.event.transform.y + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
}
```

I am new to D3 and would appreciate any help pointing me in the correct direction.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)

Comment: @SaeedAdelMehraban The question is for d3 v4.0.

Comment: @Owen You always can port a v3 to v4.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks its funny that he asked to be "pointed in the correct direction"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Arrows

To add arrows at the end of the line you need to define a marker using SVG. Only slight modifications are required to update the d3 v3 code to do this with v4. The example you provided sets up three arrow definitions (one for each type of relationship) but to create a single one you can use this:

```
svg.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 20)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 8)
    .attr("markerHeight", 8)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

The values of `markerWidth`, `markerHeight`, `refX`, `refY` are significant and determine the placement of the markers - unfortunately I don't know how they interplay with the `viewBox` or the circle radius so these were selected by trial and error.

No need to capture the marker as a variable because it will be referred to using a URL specifier as follows:

```
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.type); })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

## Labels

Again, slight modifications to the v3 code will work. Text labels need to be appended to the SVG separately, not as children of the nodes, and translated independently in the `ticked` function.

To set up the labels:

```
var text = svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels").selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g");

text.append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", "0.7em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

And then to translate them to the right location when the force simulation ticks:

```
  function ticked() {
    // ...
    text
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  }
```

The horizontal offset is defined by the value of `x` when setting up the labels (14 in this case).

## Together

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owen_rodda/55zk55ut/16/) for the complete example.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: I would add a ".labels {pointer-events: none;}" to the fiddle CSS so the text is not clickable.