# Selectable zoomable force directed graph in D3v4 with arrows for edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm pretty new to D3.js and I would like to draw a spacialized and force layout graph. I have the code from [this exemple](http://emptypipes.org/2017/04/29/d3v4-selectable-zoomable-force-directed-graph/) ("d3v4-selectable-zoomable-force-directed-graph") which works great for zooming and panning.

Before that, I took the basic code (Force-Directed Graph from Mike Bostock) and I added arrows to the edges following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439608/d3-4-0-graph-with-directed-edges-and-labels).

Well, now my problem is to merge both. I tried without any results to add zooming to the basic D3.js force layout example so I'm trying to add arrows on edges to the second, but it does not work at all :/

Basically, I've downloaded the "d3v4-selectable-zoomable-force-directed-graph" example supra. and I've added this code:

```
    svg.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 20)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 8)
    .attr("markerHeight", 8)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
// code //
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.type); })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

I assume this is related to a moving and zooming issue of the edges and arrows and of lost of properties, but I'm afraid I can't deal with it alone. Does some of you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: The link to Mike Bostock's force directed graph > https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Resolved, thank you!